# Java ignore NullPointerException in database?

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception

I am new to Java coming from C#. Been trying to figure something out, but I can't get it right.

So let's say we have a table with the following contents:

```
_id | body                       | partner_jid | bin_id
----------------------------------------------------------
1   | Hello                      | jid_2933219 | group_30
2   | null                       | jid_2933219 | group_30
3   | !cmd                       | jid_2933219 | group_30
4   | An                         | jid_2933219 | group_30
5   | Example                    | jid_2933219 | group_30
```

Okay, so basically what needs to happen, is that the row body gets scanned for text that starts with "!cmd" (and if it gets found, do something). BUT, once it comes down to number 2, the program quits and returns a NullPointerException.

I currently have this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            System.out.println("Load driver success");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:data.db");

            String query = "Select * from messagesTable";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(result.next()) {
                int msgId = result.getInt("_id");
                String msgBody = result.getString("body");
                String usrId = result.getString("partner_jid");
                String grpId = result.getString("bin_id");
                if(grpId.equals("group_30")){
                    System.out.println(msgId);
                    System.out.println(msgBody.toLowerCase().trim());
                    System.out.println(usrId);
                    if(msgBody.contains("!cmd")){
                        System.out.println("Command found!");
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Read file error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
1
Hello
jid_2933219
Read file error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dysanix.message.scanner.main.main(main.java:26)
```

How do I make it ignore the NullPointerException and just continue to the next one?

```
if(msgBody.contains("!cmd")){
   System.out.println("Command found!");
}
```

If I remove this line, it doesn't give the NullPointerException and just prints the whole table like it should, but I need to make it do something when a !cmd gets found, so how would I go around doing this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Avoidance is often the best preventative measure.  Instead of using the sad-yet-common practice of variable.equals("constant") use the ihe (I hate exceptions) technique of "constant".equals(variable).  The ihe technique is guaranteed to never throw a null pointer exception for string comparison.

Comment: Also, start using the Apache Commons Lang StringUtils class.  it provides many null safe versions of string methods (for example: contains).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `boolean` and (`&&`) to check for `null` before checking if it contains your `String`. Something like

```
if (msgBody != null && msgBody.contains("!cmd")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is the answer! I checked for "null" instead of null. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either simply add a null check for each String; however that's rather crude and not pretty. If I were you I'd use StringUtils of org.apache.commons.lang3 package. There you can do things like StringUtils.startsWith, or StringUtils.contains... etc. See Class. But all those checks will be NullSafe for you, and they look pretty and do most work for you.